# Tridion 2011 Sp1 allow to publish revision version of the component to staging target

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Here is a scenario: I have a Page which have Component A. Component A have few linked components B and C. If Editor modifies component B and want to publish to staging target while component still in the workflow so Reviewer can view the changes on staging server before approve component B. When editor preview component he can see the changes, but when he publish to staging target it will grab the last checked in version of the Component A, which still linked to the unmodified version of Component B. How to pragmatically overwrite the default behavior to allow Editor publish his changes to staging environment before completing activity for the item?

Also, when component B inserted directly on the second page I was able to publish from VBScript from workflow automated activity using the following:

```
Dim strItemURI
strItemURI = CurrentWorkItem.GetItem(2).ID

Dim oComp
Set oComp = TDSE.GetObject(strItemURI, 1)
Call oComp.Publish("tcm:0-13-65537", True, True, False)
Set oComp = Nothing
```

FinishActivity "Automatic Activity ""Publish to Staging"" Finished"

Do I need to write custom resolver to accomplish above scenario to allow modified version of linked components published to staging environment while in workflow?

Any idea or samples will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Updated:

I'm trying to create TBB, which will replace modified version of the item in the package. Any idea on this? Here is some code:

```
public void Transform(Engine engine, Package package)
{
try
{

 _publicationID = engine.PublishingContext.ResolvedItem.Item.Id.PublicationId;

 string stagingTarget = Settings.GetSetting("StagingTargetUri");
 PublicationTarget target = new PublicationTarget(new TcmUri(stagingTarget),                   engine.GetSession());

if(engine.PublishingContext.ResolvedItem.PublicationTarget!=null){
if     (stagingTarget.Contains(engine.PublishingContext.ResolvedItem.PublicationTarget.Id.ToString()))
{
foreach (Item item in package.GetAllByType(ContentType.Component))
{

VersionedItem versionedItem = (VersionedItem)engine.GetObject(item);

if (versionedItem.LockType.HasFlag(LockType.InWorkflow))
{
Component componentInWorkflow =
(Component)engine.GetObject(new TcmUri(versionedItem.Id.ItemId,   versionedItem.Id.ItemType, versionedItem.Id.PublicationId, 0));



package.Remove(item);
Item mainComponent=  package.CreateTridionItem(ContentType.Component,componentInWorkflow);
package.PushItem(mainComponent);

}
}
}
}

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
throw ex;
}
}
```

Comment: Is Component A also in Workflow or checked out by anyone?

Comment: Can you also describe the minimum level of approval for your target, and the approval status of each item when you perform the publish action?

Comment: Nickoli, Component A not in the workflow, but because it's have linked component B it will not let me publish version 0 of component B. I think it because it still linked to latest checked in version.

Comment: Staging have Default_Draft and Live have default_live. This can be changed, since we are trying to implement custom workflow.

Comment: Are your components published as Dynamic Component Presentations or statically embedded on the page?  The reason I ask is because in your code you are calling "publish" on the component, but if it's statically embedded, it should trigger republishing on the page and all the last major versions of the CPs on it.

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation:

> You can publish an item in Workflow if it meets the minimum approval
>   status set for the Publishing Target. If the item is in Workflow and
>   does not meet the minimum approval status, the Content Manager
>   publishes the last checked-in version of the item.

This means that you need to:

- Set the `Minimum Approval Status` on your `Publication target` as something like **"Staging"**

[image]

- As a first step on your Workflow set the `Approval Status` for your component to **"Staging"**

[image]

Comment: I believe if item is still in workflow doesn't matter what minimum approval status you have. This matter when publishing happens after item was approved and out of the workflow. When Editor modify the component it will be in the workflow "Create or Edit Component" than he wants to publish this version of the component to Staging for review and complete his activity. I was able to publish pragmatically by adding Automated Activity step and use VBScript, but this work only when component A was modified and directly added to the page.